# Коллекция в контроллере

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

В коллекцию через ajax приходят данные в List. Как правильно их обработать и передать в метод? Спасибо!
Контроллер:

```java
List<Forma> list = new ArrayList<>();
    @PostMapping(value="/save", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public String postCustomer(@RequestBody List<Forma> formDates) {

        list.addAll(formDates);
//      Forma forma = new Forma();
//
//      String start = forma.getStart();
//      String end = forma.getEnd();
//
//      service.result(start, end);
        return "Post Successfully!";
    }
```

В сервис хочу передать значения, которые приходят в листе такого вида:

```js
{startTime: "2019-05-02", endTime: "2019-05-17"}
```

Скрипт

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#taskForm").submit(function(event) {
        // Prevent the form from submitting via the browser.
        event.preventDefault();
        let formTask = {
                startTime : $("#startTime").val(),
                endTime : $("#endTime").val()
        }

    function ajaxPost(){
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            contentType : "application/json",
            accept: 'text/plain',
            url : window.location + "api/logtime/save",
            data : JSON.stringify(listTasks),
            dataType: 'text',
            success : function(result) {

}
```

Comment: У тебя не лист, а одиночный объект вообще-то.

Comment: ок, как тогда можно выйти из этой ситуации?

Answer (score 0):

Предполагаю что объект Forma имеет вид

```
public class Forma {

    private Date startTime;
    private Date endTime;

    // getters & setters
}
```

В таком случае достаточно обернуть передаваемые объекты в массив

```
POST /save HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
content-length: 112

[
    {"startTime": "2019-05-02", "endTime": "2019-05-17"},
    {"startTime": "2019-10-02", "endTime": "2019-10-17"}
]
```

Comment: Вместо даты - строки. передаю строки

Comment: Достаточно Date переделать в String ;)

Comment: та понятно :). но получил ошибку JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of...